# Why won't Office 2011 install on Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, ms-office, install

I'm trying to install Office on my mother-in-law's MacBook.  The installer fails every time with:

12/28/12 12:26:42 PM    installd[1798]  PackageKit: Install Failed: PKG: pre-install scripts for "com.microsoft.office.all.quit.pkg.14.2.0"
Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 UserInfo=0x103b1da10 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Office Installer”." {
    NSFilePath = "./preinstall";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cOffice Installer\U201d.";
    NSURL = "#Office2011_all_quit_14.2.0.pkg -- file://localhost/Volumes/Microsoft%20Office%202011/Office%20Installer.pkg";
    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.microsoft.office.all.quit.pkg.14.2.0";
}

Outside of the timestamp, installd process ID and userinfo number, it's always the same message.

Here's the hardware overview from system_profiler:

```
  Model Name: MacBook
  Model Identifier: MacBook2,1
  Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed: 2 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory: 2 GB
  Bus Speed: 667 MHz
  Boot ROM Version: MB21.00A5.B07
  SMC Version (system): 1.13f3
```

I've updated all of the software using Software Update and I've repaired permissions on the hard drive.

Comment: Can you post hard-drive specs? [Here's](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/admin/item/a13786c1-f9e5-4625-b8a3-caa8edc31276) the full system requirements.

Comment: Has Office ever been installed on that machine? If so, the installer may be reading receipts or preferences that make it think this machine is ineligible. Another thing to consider is the media you are trying to install from. A download? Try a fresh one. A DVD? Try cleaning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to answer this the day after I posted the question, but my in-law's Internet connection wasn't being cooperative.

I was only able to install Office after we wiped the machine and reinstalled Snow Leopard.  I have no idea what the actual problem was.  The machine was really slow anyway and now it's running like new.

I guess the old rule about Microsoft Windows extends to MS Office for Mac:  format and reinstall.  :(